# Trigger email using java after 2 hours

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I want to trigger an email with user details in that email after two hours if the user updated basic information. I used TimerTask class in java and it was working fine. But planning to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java. 
My question is,

1. Since using multithreading, I must avoid race condition (For that I am using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java or TimerTask.java).
2. User can update his/her basic details N number of times within two hours.So, after two hours I have to send mail with updated details.How to track that timing?
3. Is there any better approach for this?
4. Since using multithreading, What are the scenarios I have to cover?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick approach is, each time when you do such update email, capture all the necessary data (i.e. copy it) within the task so you totally avoid locking concern. Given your application I think this is sensible and sufficient.

For 2) depends on if you wish to do conflation (i.e. keep only the latest task in the queue) or you wishes to just let me be.